# Simulate iOS-App on iPhone 5 crashs with Resolution

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, resolution

just now I run my iOS-App, built with Xcode, on my iPhone 5 (4 inch-Display). Before this last debug, the view scale correctly to the 4 inch-resolution. But now, my iPhone shows me the App in 3.5 inch-Resolution. I can't find the mistake in Xcode...

Please help me.

Sorry for my english mistakes, I'm from Germany.

Comment: I think you have to click on "Use Autolayout" option in File inspector for xib or storyboard.

Comment: Yes. Must it unchecked?

Comment: Ok, it is checked. But the problem remains.

Comment: Is Default-568h@2x.png present in your project ?

Comment: Check if you still having the 'Retina 4-inch' default image on your Project Target Settings

Comment: The 'use Autolayout' checkbox should be checked IF you want to use autolayout. Else, if you have a Default image for 4-inch display added to your project, iOS will try to scale your app to 4 inch display. Your auto resizing masks will determine if your view looks correct on 4 inch display. Check if you have a Default-568h@2x.png added to your project and also added to the target settings.

Comment: Oh god... :) Yes, now it works!
It's funny, because before it works without the Default-568h@2x.png...

Comment: Is there any problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you still have "Default-568h@2x.png" splash image sized for iPhone5 (640 x 1136) in your project.